# Less.js: getting selector for a specific context

Tags: css-selectors, less, element

I am using less.js (1.5.0, 1.6.0, 2.1.1 tested) and don't seem to be able to override a selector with a specific context. I would be grateful for shedding light on me whether my less is less-compatible or not

*Version 1:*

```
.icon.icon-text {
    &.icon-save { background-image: url('patth/to/file.svg'); }
    #specific-grid &.icon-save { background-image: url('patth/to/file.svg') }
}
```

*Version 2:*

```
.icon.icon-text {
    &.icon-save {
        background-image: url('patth/to/file.svg');

        #specific-grid & { background-image: url('patth/to/file.svg') }
    }
}
```

Both versions do not generate the contextualized selector. How should I go about it?

Comment: What is your desired end result CSS?

Comment: `#specific-grid .icon.icon-text.icon-save {}`

Comment: Your version 2 seems to generate: `#specific-grid .icon.icon-text.icon-save {
  background-image: url('patth/to/file.svg');
}`

Comment: Somehow I can't get it to work with less.js